# flexsider not working in Bootstrap tabs and jquery tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, flexslider, jquery-tabs

i am trying to put flexsider inside bootstrap tab. First tab is working but from second tab flexsider is not working. But after some all tabs are working fine with flex slider. please help me. Is flexsider is compatible with bootstrap tab or jquery tab. please help with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You Might have missed tabs plugin code for this. following is code snippet for same.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/twitterbootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#tabs').tab();
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps to you.